# php_memcache extension in wamp

Tags: php, memcached

I installed the memcached extension service .

Started it using

> memcached.exe -d start

command and it works fine.

Now I added the php_memcache.dll file in

> php/php5.5.12/ext

folder and included the

> extension=php_memcache.dll

in php.ini(Apache's php.ini) file

php_memcache does show up in the php extensions.

Now when I run the below code , it throws a notice saying

> undefined variable isMemcacheAvailable

. So does that mean still memcache is not properly installed ?

```
if (class_exists('Memcache')) {
    $memcache = new Memcache;
    $isMemcacheAvailable = @$memcache->connect('127.0.0.1');
    }
if ($isMemcacheAvailable) {
    echo "yes";
}
```

Comment: is the variable `$memcache` initialized? That would mean the extension is installed but you are unable to connect to memcache

Comment: Also i would remove the @ so that you will see the errors properly

Comment: Yeah but by removing @ , we would see errors only if class_exists('Memcache') evaluated to true . By the way , thanks for the concern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two memcache extensions memcache and memcached.

It looks like you have installed memcached but you need memcache (i.e. php_memcache.dll)

Download Link: https://pecl.php.net/package/memcache/3.0.8/windows

Edit: Sorry I misread your post above and read that you had installed php_memcached.dll however you do actually say you've installed what I've suggested, are you sure the correct DLL has been added?

Comment: Thanks a lot :) actually the dll I had installed was not for PHP 5.5.12 version may be . But I downloaded the corresponding thread-safe php_memcache.dll from the link you gave and extracted the zip folder to www/bin/php/ext folder and restarted all services . It works flawlessly now .